# [Angular]What is happening when we take two controllerAs reference as "vm"?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to understand what exactly happening in below code.

I took two directives named widget and filter(We can say sibilings).

**For both I gave the controllerAs reference as "vm" then it is not working.**

- It means only one controllerAs reference is exposing to DOM
  (Here widget controllerAs ref exposing. I don't know why?)

**If I change anyone of them controllerAs  reference to  something else then it is working fine.**

- Both controllerAs references are exposing to DOM getting expected result.

Could you please explain this functionality in angular.
how angular evaluate when we give same controllerAs reference for directive(Here those are siblings).

**If it is ambiguous ?**
 As each controller has their own scope then how it will be ambiguous ?

[Here you can see the issue.](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/12211/)

This is my directive structure.

```
    <div ng-app="myApp">
      {{tt.name}}
      <body-dir>
        <icon-dir>
          <filter-dir>

          </filter-dir>
        </icon-dir>

        <widget-dir>

        </widget-dir>
      </body-dir>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('filterController', function filterController($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.test = "From filter controller";
  alert("filter");
});
myApp.controller('widgetController', ['$scope', function widgetController($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.widget = "From widget controller";
  alert("widget");
}])
myApp.directive('bodyDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function($scope) {
      alert('body-dir');
    }
  };
});

myApp.directive('widgetDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: 'widgetController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    template: "<span>{{vm.widget}}</span>",
    link: function($scope) {
      alert('widget-dir');
    }
  };

});
myApp.directive('filterDir', function() {
  return {
    controller: 'filterController',
    controllerAs: 'vm', // If I change something else it's working fine
    restrict: 'E',
    template: "<span>{{vm.test}}</span>",
    link: function($scope) {

      alert('filter-dir');
    }
  };
});
myApp.directive('iconDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function($scope) {
      alert('icon-dir');
    }
  };

});
```

Comment: You should isolate at least one (of the 2 directives) scope to have your code working fine by adding in the returned object scope : { } or scope : { /* what you'd like the inner (directive) scope to access from the parent controller  */ }

Comment: I tried by enabling the isolated scope for body directive but that not solved the issue

Comment: I meant the siblings directives :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of your directives defines its own scope, so they all use the outer scope (i.e. the root scope, here), and all try to assign their controller to the property `vm` of this scope. So the last one wins.

Basically, your template code causes the following to happen:

```
$rootScope.vm = filterController;
$rootscope.vm = widgetController;
```

Comment: If it doesn't have scope in the directive it should take parent scope right?
Here body directive scope.
Why it is going under rootscope?

Comment: I tried by enabling the isolated scope for body directive.
but still that is the case

Comment: The body directve doesn't have its own scope either, so it also uses the rootScope. Defining an isolate scope for body won't change much: now both directives will try to initialize the body's scope.vm with their own controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should isolate at least one (of the 2 directives) scope to have your code working fine by adding in the returned object

```
    scope : { } or 
    scope : { 
       /* pass here what you'd like the inner (directive) scope 
          to access from the parent controller */ 
         }


    myApp.directive('widgetDir', function() {
     return {
       restrict: 'E',
       controller: 'widgetController',
       controllerAs: 'vm',
       template: "<span>{{vm.widget}}</span>",
       scope : {

       },

       link: function($scope) {
         alert('widget-dir');
       }
   };

 });
```

Comment: I know that way it works.
but I want to know why the way I mentioned won't work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/12212/ Actually without using controller aliases at all the code works just fine and I think by giving aliases to the the controllers we override the way Angular keeps track of scopes in this case  :)

Comment: it's good point but for best practice we should use this reference right?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/12226/ I changed your code to illustrate the properties that Angular puts on a $scope object. Open the console and see that vm is just a property on the filter directive scope, so by giving an allias we reduce the actual scope to the vm I guess

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sibling directives to have different inherited scopes, use `scope: true`:

```
    <icon-dir>
    </icon-dir>

    <widget-dir>
    </widget-dir>
```

```
myApp.directive('widgetDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    //DECLARE inherited scope
    scope: true,
    controller: 'widgetController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    template: "<span>{{vm.widget}}</span>",
    link: function($scope) {
      alert('widget-dir');
    }
  };

});
```

```
myApp.directive('filterDir', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    //DECLARE inherited scope
    scope: true,
    controller: 'filterController',
    controllerAs: 'vm', // If I change something else it's working fine
    template: "<span>{{vm.test}}</span>",
    link: function($scope) {

      alert('filter-dir');
    }
  };
});
```

The inherited child scope (`scope:true`) will then have the `vm` property of the controller on different scopes for each sibling.